# Calling a variable have user input from a different method

Tags: c#

i have fixed the question:

The code is working until it hit the MultyMethod it stop because i have tried to take the output from the SumMethod and do another calculation in the MultyMethod.

So my question is i have tried to use the same input from SumMethod in the MultyMethod but it does not work well i have used all the reference in my mind or i could think of but still it told me : the name "SumMethod" need a reference to call it or you forgetting to use a reference. So how i could use the same input from the SumMethod in the MultyMethod!!

```
using System;

namespace example
{
    class Program
    {

        public int number1 { set; get; }
        public int number2 { set; get; }
        public int sum { set; get; }
        public int multy { set; get; }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var value = SumMethod();
            var values = MultyMethod();

            ResultMethod(value.number1, value.number2, value.sum, values.multy);
        }
        public static Program SumMethod()
        {
                var input = new Program();
                int i = 0;
                Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter your first number: ");
                input.number1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine(" Please Enter your second number: ");
                input.number2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                int[] arr = new int[] { input.number1, input.number2 };
                do
                {
                    input.sum += arr[i];
                    i++;
                } while (i < 2);

                return input;
            }
            public static Program MultyMethod()
            {
                var input = new Program();
                // here is the issue i am trying to get the input from the previous method instead of asking the user to input the numbers again
                // i have tried this 
                //input.number1 = new input.SumMethod();

                // and also have tried to use this reference 
                //value.SumMethod(); // since the inputs store in this variable but it does not make since to call it this way ><

                // i have also tried to use this way

                //input.number1 = new SumMethod();
            return input;

            }

            public static void ResultMethod(int number1, int number2, int sum, int multy)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" The first number is: ");
                Console.WriteLine(number1);
                Console.WriteLine(" The second number is: ");
                Console.WriteLine(number2);
                Console.WriteLine(" The sum of the number is: ");
                Console.WriteLine(sum);
                Console.WriteLine(" The multiplication of the numbers is: ");
                Console.WriteLine(multy);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exception did you get? and on which line?

Comment: Where SumMethod is defined?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. But the code you provided does not compile because of writing errors or missing items impossible to interpret. Please try to better explain your issue, your dev env and the data structures, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: I am so sorry i fixed the question

Comment: @Skarali Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thank you!

Comment: @AnnL. Yes it helps a lot... Do you know how i do that please!!

Comment: Under the number and arrow icons to the left hand of my answer text, there should be a grey checkmark.  If you click on that check mark, it should "accept" my answer. If you hover over the grey check mark, it should explain what to do.

Comment: @AnnL. Done thanks to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your basic problem is that the variable `input`, which you wish to reference in `MultyMethod`, is internal to `SumMethod`. Therefore, `MultyMethod` can't access it.

You define another variable called `input` in `MultyMethod`, but that is NOT the same variable. It's a separate one, the scope of which is just `MultyMethod`, and can't be accessed outside of it.

So, how to do what you want. I hope you don't mind that I'm also going to make some suggestions about how you could better organize this code.

First, you could define `input` outside of `SumMethod`, as a class-level static variable. In that case, it could be accessed by both `SumMethod` and `MultyMethod`.  The following is a short excerpt (with some lines removed to save space):

```
class Program
{

    public int number1 { set; get; }
    public int number2 { set; get; }
    public int sum { set; get; }
    public int multy { set; get; }

    public static Program input = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // etc.
    }

    public static Program SumMethod()
    {
        input = new Program();
        // rest of the code
        return input;
    }
  
    public static Program MultyMethod()
    {
        input = Program.input; // this is a static reference.
        // desired multiplication code
        return input;
    }
```

Another option would be to parameterize `MultyMethod` so it takes a `Program` as a parameter, representing the input:

```
public static Program MultyMethod(Program input)
{
    // You probably don't want to have the same variable have both your sum
    // and your multiplication results.
    Program newVar = new Program() { number1 = input.number1, number2 = input.number2 };   

    // Do things with newVar in place of "input"
   
    return newVar;
}
```

Then you'd change `Main` to look like this:

```
var value = SumMethod();
var values = MultyMethod(value);
```

An even better version would separate getting the input from performing the summing. So you could do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = GetInput();
    var value = SumMethod(input);
    var values = MultyMethod(input);
    
    // do other things
}
```

Finally, the whole thing would be better if you had separate classes for all three of the following:

- The program itself
- The input parameters and results
- The multiplication and sum methods

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought about having them in different class but cause i am learning C# so it would be better to be basic and then move forward with classes and extend some classes from another class

Comment: ok if to add two number i used input.sum += arr[i];

Comment: why it is not printing for the multiplication if give me a zero when i do result.multy *= arr[i];

Comment: Because `result.multy` probably started out with a value of 0!  And anything multiplied by 0 will be 0.  Initialize it to 1 before starting your loop!